# Does a post hoc hypothesis have the same evidentiary value as an apriori hypothesis without a prediction?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Philosophers often say that a hypothesis that predicts data D is better than a hypothesis that accommodates data D after the fact. But what about a hypothesis that exists before data D but doesn't actually predict data D? Is that still better than a hypothesis that accommodates for data D?

Suppose you are a Christian and you're feeling depressed. You decide to read the Bible and the very first verse you read is about God sending down a sign to people he loves. That very same day, you play the lottery and ask God for help and you end up winning the lottery with a 1 in 1,000,000 chance. You start wondering if this is evidence of the Christian God intervening to help you out. Let's call this hypothesis H.

Now suppose you are a person playing a game show. In this game show, you guess a number between 1 and 1,000,000. You are hoping you win. You guess it correctly. Suppose you come up with a hypothesis that there's some God out there who specifically helps you and only you during game shows, and that is why you won. Let's call this hypothesis H2.

Note that the second hypothesis is completely post hoc. It was designed to accomodate the datum. The first hypothesis also seems post hoc yet not completely. The conception of a Christian God existed before the event. Him being a christian exised before that event. However, there is no prediction made within the conception of God or the Bible that says you would win the lottery.

However, **in your head**, before the lottery's results were drawn out, you did technically **hope** that the Christian God would help you.

Given that the chance of both events are the same, should each hypothesis be treated as equally ridiculous? Or should the second hypothesis, because it seems to be completely post hoc, be given less credence?

Comment: The chances of both events are not the same. In the first situation, there are two events: E1: reading a verse about God sending a sign; and E2: winning the lottery. In the second situation, there is only one event: E3: winning the game show. The probability of E1 and E2 happening together on the same day is lower than the probability of E3 happening, and justifies the hypothesis much better because E1 has a strong connection with the hypothesis, whereas E2 and E3 do not have that strong connection.

Comment: (This question would actually be well-suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com )

Comment: Tukey once advocated confirmatory data analysis which tries to extract post hoc hypothesis or patterns from evidential data, thus it’s not ridiculous to form post hoc H, though it maybe mundane to have such disposition for average people. Otoh to form ad hoc universal hypothesis has been always the holy grail of the dialectitions and the more wise albeit lots theoretical obstacles…